# DropDownListFor not displaying the SelectedValue set in the ViewModel

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, dropdownlistfor

I'm using a `DropDownListFor` to display a list of Weeks in an entry. If you edit an existing entry, the Week selected displays just fine.

When you go to create a new entry, the selected value is my `optionLabel`. I want to select the first Week that has a StartDate that is greater than  `DateTime.Now`.

When I apply a breakpoint, the correct ID is set as the SelectedValue of the SelectList, but it doesn't display in the `DropDownListFor`, nor is the option "selected" when I look at the Developer Tools. Any help would be great.

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.reportData.WeekId, Model.weeksList, "-- Select Week Of --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Controller:

```
int currentWeekOfId = selectableWeeksList.Where(w => w.WeekStartDate > DateTime.Now).Select(s => s.Id).FirstOrDefault();
_3PViewModel vm = new _3PViewModel()
{
    weeksList = new SelectList(selectableWeeksList, "Id", "FullWeek", currentWeekOfId)
};
return PartialView(vm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `DropDownListFor` take first your `model.reportData.WeekId` value.
Like you are creating a new entity, i imagine `reportData.WeekId` is `NULL`, so the helper take the first item in SelectList with `NULL` or empty value.

Instead of initializing your `Model.weeksList` with `currentWeekOfId` you should init your new entity model, something like that :

```
public Action Create() {
    int currentWeekOfId = selectableWeeksList.Where(w => w.WeekStartDate > DateTime.Now).Select(s => s.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    _3PViewModel vm = new _3PViewModel()
    {
        weeksList = new SelectList(selectableWeeksList, "Id", "FullWeek"),
        reportData = nezw ReportData() { WeekId = currentWeekOfId }
    }
    return PartialView(vm);
}
```

Comment: THAT WAS IT! I had the reportData, but I had it as...

reportData = new tbl3PReports()

...instead of...

reportData = new tbl3PReports() { WeekId = currentWeekOfId }